# Re-enable the idle timer prior to app crashing out or user hitting the main exit button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, idle-timer

I am writing an app that disables the idle timer. How do I re-enable it prior to app crashing out or user hitting the main exit button? This could be real bad by draining the battery otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reenable it in the `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method.

You can use this: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO]`. Don't forget to disable it again when your app becomes active.